# Query on support for profiling native unmanaged C++ code in Visual Studio 2012 & 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, profiling, visual-studio-2013, instrumentation

I've installed Visual Studio 2012 & 2013 Professional for evaluation with all the latest updates with a view to purchasing a licence if all goes well...

I'm interested in profiling and instrumenting native unmanaged C++ code, but am running into difficulties.

I can get Sampling-based performance profiling for native C++ code working OK in the IDE for VS2012 but not for VS2013.

I can't get Instrumentation-based performance profiling working for native C++ in the IDE in either of VS2012 or VS2013.

The C++ code is being called from C# GUI. The C# and managed C++ calls are getting profiled, but not the unmanged C++ code.

Is this possible to achieve, either via the IDE or else through the command line?

The Visual Studio documentation is pretty poor in this area.

Does anyone have any good web links as to how to get this all setup?

Are any of these features only available in the Premium or other higher editions?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it.

In the end it turned out to be it was instrumenting the native DLL but then loading a different uninstrumented version of it into the process.

All working fine now across both VS versions.

Comment: Would you mind providing more details? I also have a mixed project that I want to profile in VS 2012. The Profiler can handle the managed code, but when it comes to the native code, it doesn't show any debug symbols. It treats all of the native code as a call to PInvoke.